# Azure Storage Table [Python] - Batch does not fail

Tags: python-2.7, azure, transactions, etag, azure-table-storage

I am currently developing a Python (2.7) application that uses the Azure Table Storage service via the Azure Python package .As far as I have read from Azure's REST API, batching operations create atomic transactions. So, if one of the operations fails, the whole batch fails and no operations are executed.

The problem that I have encountered is the following:
The method below receives via the "rows" parameter a list of dicts. Some have an **ETag** set (provided from a previous query).

If the **ETag** is set, attempt a merge operation. Otherwise, attempt an insert operation. Since there are multiple processes that may modify the same entity, it is required to address the concurrency problem via the "**if_match**" parameter of the merge_entity function. If the merge/insert operations are individual operations (not included in batch), the system **works as expected**, raising an Exception if the ETags do not match. 
Unfortunately, this **does *not* happen if they are wrapped in "begin_batch" / "commit_batch"** calls. The entities are merged (wrongly) even though the **ETags DO NOT match**.

I have provided below both the code and the test case used. Also ran some manual tests several time with the same conclusion.

I am unsure of how to approach this problem. Am I doing something wrong or is it an issue with the Python package?

The code used is the following:

```
def persist_entities(self, rows):
    success = True
    self._service.begin_batch()        #If commented, works as expected (fails)
    for row in rows:
        print row
        etag = row.pop("ETag")
        if not etag:
            self._service.insert_entity(self._name,
                                        entity=row)
        else:
            print "Merging " + etag
            self._service.merge_entity(self._name,
                                       row["PartitionKey"],
                                       row["RowKey"],
                                       row, if_match=etag)
    try:            #Also tried with the try at the begining of the code
        self._service.commit_batch()       #If commented, works as expected (fails)
    except WindowsAzureError:
        print "Failed to merge"
        self._service.cancel_batch()
        success = False
    return success
```

The test case used:

```
def test_fail_update(self):
        service = self._conn.get_service()
        partition, new_rows = self._generate_data()   #Partition key and list of dicts
        success = self._wrapper.persist_entities(new_rows)   #Inserts fresh new entity
        ok_(success)                                           #Insert succeeds
        rows = self._wrapper.get_entities_by_row(partition) #Retreives inserted data for ETag
        eq_(len(rows), 1)
        for index in rows:
            row = rows[index]
            data = new_rows[0]
            data["Count"] = 155                       #Same data, different value
            data["ETag"] = "random_etag"              #Change ETag to a random string
            val = self._wrapper.persist_entities([data])              #Try to merge
            ok_(not val)            #val = True for merge success, False for merge fail.
            #It's always True when operations in batch. False if operations out of batch 
            rows1 = self._wrapper.get_entities_by_row(partition)
            eq_(len(rows1), 1)
            eq_(rows1[index].Count, 123)
            break

    def _generate_data(self):
        date = datetime.now().isoformat()
        partition = "{0}_{1}_{2}".format("1",
                                         Stats.RESOLUTION_DAY, date)
        data = {
            "PartitionKey": partition,
            "RowKey": "viewitem",
            "Count": 123,
            "ETag": None
        }
        return partition, [data]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a bug in the SDK (v0.8 and earlier).  I've created an issue and checked in a fix. It will be part of the next release.  You can pip install from the git repo to test the fix.
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/149

Comment: Thank you for your answer and implication. I'm looking forward to your next release. I will also test the fix soon enough and provide you with feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Azure Table Storage has a new python library in preview release that is available for installation via pip. To install use the following pip command

```
pip install azure-data-tables
```

There are some differences with how you are performing batching and how batching works in the newest library.

1. A batch operation can only be committed on entities contained with the same partition key.
2. A batch operation can not contain multiple operations on the same row key.
3. Batches will only be committed if the entire batch is successful, if the `send_batch` raises an error, there will be no updates made.

With this being stated, the create and update operations work the same as a non-batching create and update. For example:

```
from azure.data.tables import TableClient, UpdateMode
table_client = TableClient.from_connection_string(conn_str, table_name="myTable")

batch = table_client.create_batch()
batch.create_entity(entity1)
batch.update_entity(entity2, etag=etag, match_condition=UpdateMode.MERGE)
batch.delete_entity(entity['PartitionKey'], entity['RowKey'])

try:
    table_client.send_batch(batch)
except BatchErrorException as e:
    print("There was an error with the batch")
    print(e)
```

For more samples with the new library, check out the [samples](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/master/sdk/tables/azure-data-tables/samples) page on the repository.

(FYI, I am a Microsoft employee on the Azure SDK for Python team)

Comment: It seems that `commit_batch` was renamed `send_batch`

Comment: @MaxLap thank you for catching that, I have updated my response.

Comment: Is this still the proper way to do batching? The documentation does not reference any of these commands for TableClient.

Comment: @MarkoTankosic the API did change, here is a reference link to an updated sample: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/main/sdk/tables/azure-data-tables/samples/sample_batching.py